# A simple Relative layout, align to parent right not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have made a simple **relative layout** which only contains 3 `TextView` , code is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    > 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!--Why this "age" TextView is not align to parent right?-->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like the 2nd `TextView`(id="age") to be positioned to right, so I use `layout_alignParentRight="true"`, however, it always show after the 1st `TextView`(id="name"), why? Why it does not go to the parent right (rightmost) ?

Answer (score 9):

remove this:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
```

from the age TextView